# Find all Subpartition name

Tags: oracle, partitioning, long-integer, subpartition

The Table was subpartitioned  based on column(INSTANCE) who's value can be '1' or '2'. Want to list  all subpartition name which contains INSTANCE value as '2'

```
select * from user_tab_subpartitions sp where table_name='TEST' and sp.NUM_ROWS >0
and to_char(HIGH_VALUE)='2';
```

ERROR

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got LONG
```

HIGH_VALUE  is of type LONG()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all subpartitions containing a specific value by rowids of the records with that value.

Try this query:

```
select distinct subobject_name
from user_objects obj join TEST tbl on obj.object_name = 'TEST' 
 and dbms_rowid.rowid_object(tbl.rowid) = obj.data_object_id 
where tbl.INSTANCE = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set serveroutput on;

DECLARE
 high_val VARCHAR2(32767); 
BEGIN
FOR rec IN (select PARTITION_NAME,SUBPARTITION_NAME,HIGH_VALUE  from user_tab_subpartitions sp where table_name='TEST' and sp.NUM_ROWS >0) LOOP
  high_val := rec.HIGH_VALUE;
  IF high_val LIKE '2%' THEN 
    dbms_output.put_line(rec.SUBPARTITION_NAME);
  END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: This executes faster, but the output will be written to  the console